# encrypting at clientside and decrypting the same at server in WCF REST

Tags: jquery, encryption, wcf-rest

Can we encrypt a data at client side(using jquery) and decrypt the same at server side(WCF REST service)?

Comment: What data you are asking to encrypt/decrypt.

Comment: Please specify more fully the scenario. Encryption is about securely hiding things, and to do that you need to tell us *what* you want to hide from *whom* and *why*.

Comment: You can encrypt with JavaScript, but you would still need the key at the server, and that would mean either use the same key all the time, or also send the key. That would make it mostly useless. @Deceze is right, tell us why.

Comment: its about sending credit card details....wanted to send on https network with encrypted and decrypt the same details at server

Comment: If you have HTTPS, there's no need for an additional less secure encryption layer on top of that.

Comment: Posting a question in stackoverflow is the last step to resolve a issue. but, few people in stack over flow will give negative pointing. which is not good in my concern.

Answer (score 2):

[CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) is probably your best bet for Javascript encryption.  The security of the encryption key is really the only issue.  Ultimately the key must reside on the client, which means it's not terribly secure.  If they key is shared between the client and server, there's nothing stopping your WCF REST code from decrypting it.  However, [public key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) is probably the only way it would be remotely safe.  Basic principles are outlined in the link, but the server being the only valid decrypt entity is the basic idea.